# R merge based on condition other than equality

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
date            minutes_since_midnight   value
2015-01-01      50                       2
2015-01-01      60                       1.5
2015-01-02      45                       3.3
2015-01-03      99                       5.5
```

and another dataframe looking something like this

```
date        minutes_since_midnight   other_value
2015-01-01  55                       12
2015-01-01  80                       33
2015-01-02  45                       88
```

What I want to do is add another column to the first data frame, which is the **boolean** value whether a row exists in the second data frame for an equal value in the **date** column and then a **minutes_since_midnight** which is **less than or equal to** the **minutes_since_midnight** from the first data frame. So for the above example data we'd get:

```
date        minutes_since_midnight    value  has_other_value
2015-01-01  50                        2      False
2015-01-01  60                        1.5    True
2015-01-02  45                        3.3    True
2015-01-03  99                        5.5    False
```

How can I do this?

Hope this makes sense,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not rename the variables **minutes_since_midnight** to **minutes_since_midnight1** and **minutes_since_midnight2**, merge the two data frames together then create the required **has_other_value** variable with an if else statement.

Comment: yep you're right, that would work, i will give that a go, thanks! what i was hoping for was something like merge that already takes the condition and does the work for me .. but i can write my own function doing what you suggested. Cheers

Comment: Since there are duplicate date values in both data frames, there will need to be aggregation of the second data frame before merging, to condense into a single row per date containing that date's minimum `minutes_since_midnight` value.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably join the data.frames along the lines of the other answer, then create the variable and drop unneeded columns.  But here's an option using the `dplyr` package to perform the steps as you describe them:

```
library(dplyr)
df1$has_other_value <-
  left_join(df1, df2 %>%
              group_by(date) %>%
              summarise(minMins = min(minutes_since_midnight)),
            by="date")$minMins <= df1$minutes_since_midnight

df1$has_other_value[is.na(df1$has_other_value)] <- FALSE
```

Result:

```
        date minutes_since_midnight value has_other_value
1 2015-01-01                     50   2.0           FALSE
2 2015-01-01                     60   1.5            TRUE
3 2015-01-02                     45   3.3            TRUE
4 2015-01-03                     99   5.5           FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks - that does exactly what I want, I will look into the dplyr package to get more familiar with these functions.