# Merging two different size datasets, copying the same row conditionally from smaller dataset to several rows in larger dataset

Tags: r, merge, conditional-statements

I am completely new with R, and I tried googling a representative solution for my problem for some time, but haven't found an adequate answer so far, so I hope that asking for help might solve this one here.

I should merge two different size data sets (other includes annual data: df_f, and other monthly data: df_m). I should merge the smaller df_f to the larger df_m in a way that rows of df_f are merged conditionally with df_m.

Here is a descriptive example of my problem (with some very basic reproducible numbers):

## first dataset

```
a <- c(1990)
b <- c(1980:1981)
c <- c(1994:1995)

aa <- rep("A", 1) 
bb <- rep("B", 2)
cc <- rep("C", 2)

df1 <- data.frame(comp=factor(c(aa, bb, cc))) 
df2 <- data.frame(year=factor(c(a, b, c))) 
other.columns <- rep("other_columns", length(df1))

df_f <- cbind(df1, df2, other.columns ) # first dataset
```

## second dataset

```
z <- c(10:12)
x <- c(7:12)
xx <- c(1:9)
v <- c(2:9)

w <- rep(1990, length(z))
e <- rep(1980, length(x))
ee <- rep (1981, length(xx))
r <- rep(1995, length(v))

t <- rep("A", length(z))
y <- rep("B", length(x) + length(xx))
u <- rep("C", length(v))

df3 <- data.frame(month=factor(c(z, x, xx, v))) 
df4 <- data.frame(year=factor(c(w, e, ee, r))) 
df5 <- data.frame(comp=factor(c(t, y, u))) 

df_m <- cbind(df5, df4, df3) # second dataset
```

## Output:

```
> df_m
   comp year month
1     A 1990    10
2     A 1990    11
3     A 1990    12
4     B 1980     7
5     B 1980     8
6     B 1980     9
7     B 1980    10
8     B 1980    11
9     B 1980    12
10    B 1981     1
11    B 1981     2
12    B 1981     3
13    B 1981     4
14    B 1981     5
15    B 1981     6
16    B 1981     7
17    B 1981     8
18    B 1981     9
19    C 1995     2
20    C 1995     3
21    C 1995     4
22    C 1995     5
23    C 1995     6
24    C 1995     7
25    C 1995     8
26    C 1995     9
> df_f
  comp year other.columns
1    A 1990 other_columns
2    B 1980 other_columns
3    B 1981 other_columns
4    C 1994 other_columns
5    C 1995 other_columns
```

I want to have the rows from df_f placed to df_m (store the data from df_f to new columns in df_m) according to the conditions comp, year, and month. Comp (company) needs to match always, but matching the year is conditional to month: if month is >6 then year is matched between datasets, if month is <7 then year + 1 (in df_m) is matched with year (in df_f). Note that a certain row in df_f should be placed into several rows in df_m according to the conditions.

The wanted output clarifies the problem and the goal:

## Wanted output:

```
    comp year month comp year other.columns
1     A 1990    10    A 1990 other_columns
2     A 1990    11    A 1990 other_columns
3     A 1990    12    A 1990 other_columns
4     B 1980     7    B 1980 other_columns
5     B 1980     8    B 1980 other_columns
6     B 1980     9    B 1980 other_columns
7     B 1980    10    B 1980 other_columns
8     B 1980    11    B 1980 other_columns
9     B 1980    12    B 1980 other_columns
10    B 1981     1    B 1980 other_columns
11    B 1981     2    B 1980 other_columns
12    B 1981     3    B 1980 other_columns
13    B 1981     4    B 1980 other_columns
14    B 1981     5    B 1980 other_columns
15    B 1981     6    B 1980 other_columns
16    B 1981     7    B 1981 other_columns
17    B 1981     8    B 1981 other_columns
18    B 1981     9    B 1981 other_columns
19    C 1995     2    C 1994 other_columns
20    C 1995     3    C 1994 other_columns
21    C 1995     4    C 1994 other_columns
22    C 1995     5    C 1994 other_columns
23    C 1995     6    C 1994 other_columns
24    C 1995     7    C 1995 other_columns   
25    C 1995     8    C 1995 other_columns
26    C 1995     9    C 1995 other_columns
```

Thank you very much in advance! I hope the question is clear enough, it was somewhat difficult to explain it at least.

Comment: @chris [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748346/r-merge-based-on-condition-other-than-equality)
This would help

Comment: can you check your code for creating `df_m` please, it throws errors

Comment: 'df_m' works just fine as it is at least for me

Comment: `xxx` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I missed that totally! Now it is fixed, and the example should work.

Comment: Your description of what you intend to do is unclear. In lines 1 to 18 you match the exact year for month > 6. Otherwise, the year in the first `year` column is one larger than in the second. For the lines 19 to 26 you do the opposite: exact match for month < 7, and the year in the second `year` column is larger otherwise. So which do you want? Does it depend on `comp`?

Comment: Thank you @Stibu for your comment! I had a mistake in outline there. The company should be matched always, and as you put it, the year should be matched when month >6 and if month <7 then the year in df_m data should be one larger than in df_f data. I hope that clarified! And, thanks for your persistence, I really need to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea to solve your problem is to add an extra column with the year that should be used for matching. I will use the package `dpylr` for this and other manipulation steps.

Before the tables can be combined, the numeric columns must be converted to be numeric:

```
library(dplyr)
df_m <- mutate(df_m, year = as.numeric(as.character(year)),
                     month = as.numeric(as.character(month)))
df_f <- mutate(df_f, year = as.numeric(as.character(year)))
```

The reason is that you want to be able to do numerical comparison with the month (`month > 6`) and subtract one from the year. You cannot do this with a factor.

Then I add the column to be used for matching:

```
df_m <- mutate(df_m, match_year = ifelse(month >= 7, year, year - 1))
```

And in the last step, I join the two tables:

```
df_new <- left_join(df_m, df_f, by = c("comp", "match_year" = "year"))
```

The argument `by` determines which columns of the two data frames should be matched. The output agrees with your result:

```
##    comp year month match_year other.columns
## 1     A 1990    10       1990 other_columns
## 2     A 1990    11       1990 other_columns
## 3     A 1990    12       1990 other_columns
## 4     B 1980     7       1980 other_columns
## 5     B 1980     8       1980 other_columns
## 6     B 1980     9       1980 other_columns
## 7     B 1980    10       1980 other_columns
## 8     B 1980    11       1980 other_columns
## 9     B 1980    12       1980 other_columns
## 10    B 1981     1       1980 other_columns
## 11    B 1981     2       1980 other_columns
## 12    B 1981     3       1980 other_columns
## 13    B 1981     4       1980 other_columns
## 14    B 1981     5       1980 other_columns
## 15    B 1981     6       1980 other_columns
## 16    B 1981     7       1981 other_columns
## 17    B 1981     8       1981 other_columns
## 18    B 1981     9       1981 other_columns
## 19    C 1995     2       1994 other_columns
## 20    C 1995     3       1994 other_columns
## 21    C 1995     4       1994 other_columns
## 22    C 1995     5       1994 other_columns
## 23    C 1995     6       1994 other_columns
## 24    C 1995     7       1995 other_columns
## 25    C 1995     8       1995 other_columns
## 26    C 1995     9       1995 other_columns
```